# Get top n values per group in elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, sum, aggregation

I need to get top n user due to sum of numeric field they have at different dates with elasticsearch.

For example, for the documents below get top 2:

```
doc1 -> user_id: 1, name: hasan, numeric_field: 2, date_calculated: 03-10-2015
doc2 -> user_id: 2, name: veli, numeric_field: 3, date_calculated: 03-10-2015
doc3 -> user_id: 3, name: osman, numeric_field: 1, date_calculated: 03-10-2015
doc4 -> user_id: 1, name: hasan, numeric_field: 3, date_calculated: 04-10-2015
doc5 -> user_id: 2, name: veli, numeric_field: 5, date_calculated: 04-10-2015
doc6 -> user_id: 3, name: osman, numeric_field: 7, date_calculated: 04-10-2015
doc7 -> user_id: 1, name: hasan, numeric_field: 5, date_calculated: 05-10-2015
doc8 -> user_id: 2, name: veli, numeric_field: 8, date_calculated: 05-10-2015
doc9 -> user_id: 3, name: osman, numeric_field: 9, date_calculated: 05-10-2015
```

sum of numeric_field grouped by user => `hasan : 10, veli : 16, osman : 17`

for this example, I need to get the result as top 2 -> `{ osman : 17, veli : 16 }`

What type of query should I have for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer of @ChintanShah25 and comment of @Val helped a lot. The full working solution is as below. Notice that, shard_size is important; if you don't put it as '0', you may see wrong results.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "shard_size": 0, 
        "size": 2,
        "order": {
              "sum_agg": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_agg": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "numeric_field"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, without shard_size you often get incomplete results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ElasticSearch Aggregations. I am using the following query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_agg": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "numeric_field"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result I get

```
"buckets": [
            {
               "key": "hasan",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "sum_agg": {
                  "value": 10
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "osman",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "sum_agg": {
                  "value": 17
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "veli",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "sum_agg": {
                  "value": 16
               }
            }
         ]
```

I am not able to get top n results. I tried to use Top hits aggregations inside sum aggregation but as it turns out sum aggregation does not support sub-aggregations.

You could try sorting on sum_agg values. You can read more about aggregations here.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: You don't need to use `top_hits` here, you're simply missing `"size": 2` and `"order":{"sum_agg": "desc"}` in the `user_agg` `terms` aggregation and it will work as expected.

Comment: @Val Thanks a lot! You also solved one of my problems too